# Error when project migrating Flex 3.0 to Flex 4.0

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4

We had a plan to migrating our project flex sdk 3.0 to sdk 4.0. more than 5 years we are using sdk 3.0. project build was successful but when run the application we got the following error:

```
TypeError: Error #1006: getResourceBundle is not a function.
    at mx.data.utils::ResourceTranslator$cinit()
    at global$init()[C:\depot\flex\branches\enterprise_bridgeman\frameworks\mx\data\utils\ResourceTranslator.as:30]
    at mx.data.utils::SerializationProxy$cinit()
    at global$init()[C:\depot\flex\branches\enterprise_bridgeman\frameworks\mx\data\utils\SerializationProxy.as:51]
    at _ClientRefWeb_FlexInit$/init()
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::kickOff()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2815]
    at mx.managers::SystemManager/http://www.adobe.com/2006/flex/mx/internal::preloader_completeHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\managers\SystemManager.as:2723]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at mx.preloaders::Preloader/timerHandler()[E:\dev\4.y\frameworks\projects\framework\src\mx\preloaders\Preloader.as:542]
    at flash.utils::Timer/_timerDispatch()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

Is this any version issue ? Please give any solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a similar question, maybe it will helps you: https://forums.adobe.com/thread/642964?tstart=42

Comment: I have tried some solution from that link. it didnt work for me.i have added new fds.swc to the project by downloading from https://github.com/vanjan/tour-de-flex/blob/master/libs/fds.swc